# How do I query from this table, to find the results of gpedit-fte-d@bene.com on the "name" table?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT name,mail,description,attr_id,created_dtm,modified_dtm,accept_mail_from_inet,mail_host,mail_routing_address,member,member_id,member_list,subgroup,subgroup_list,owner,owner_id,owner_list 
FROM v_ldap_mta_groups
WHERE name like 'gpedit-fte-d@bene.com';
```

However getting this error when trying to run the query,

```
Error: Internal error executing query. No results returned.
SQLState:  null
ErrorCode: 0
```

Looking for 'gpeditcon-d@bene.com' and 'gpedit-fte-d@bene.com'

Comment: `LIKE` should be `=` if you don't have any wildcards in the pattern.

Comment: No results returned isn't really an error. It just means that nothing matches.

Comment: Maybe try with this first `WHERE name like '%gp%edit%bene%com%';`

Comment: @Barmar https://imgur.com/f17d1af2-a1ec-4262-bcf5-3ffcc17e7f0b Still received this message

Comment: That link is returning an error.